# What is causing the light leak in my Hasselblad A12 back?

Tags: film, hasselblad, light-leaks

I have this consistent leak in the middle of my frames. I thought that I had at first messed up replacing the seals, but the leaks persisted after I replaced the light trap once more.

There is some damage on the edge of the back, which seems to roughly line up with the position of the leak, but not perfectly. Could this be the cause?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: This looks very similar to the sort of light leak found when using extension tubes that are missing the velvet lining to avoid reflections. Are you sure the lens optics are not causing this? Is the lens missing any reflective absorbent material? (Sorry just a shot in the dark, I'm not really familiar with this camera)

Comment: First would be to use another back to see if the problem repeats. If so then use another lens. **I.E. systematically eliminate the variables**.

Answer (score 4):

After finding very similar pictures of leaks online, and talking to an experienced repair guy, I found out that the leak is caused by an improperly closing auxiliary shutter.

The Hasselblad V series has two flaps on the back of the body, which need to make a proper seal together to prevent light that is coming through the viewfinder from reaching the film plane. In my body, these *just* don't touch perfectly snugly.

[image: photo]

Comment: update: this was not the issue. The issue lies in the back, as using the same back on a different body produced the same leaks. Actual problem in the back is yet unknown

Answer (score 0):

If it was leaking before you did the seals and it is always at the same spot then yes it is most likely the damaged area.   If you can't seal it on the inside, tape the outside.